Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1). Whilst using OAI 5G
So I have cloned the OpenAirInterface repository into my system and navigated to cmake_targets and run this command,
./build_oai -I --install-optional-packages -w USRP.
It seems to be trying to install a bunch of repositories and after a few minutes of this it attempts, libuhd4.6.0 packages and then tries to unpack a libuhd4.5.0 package and thats where it errors. I understand this may be an issue with the OAI software but seems more like a problem that people get with this 'unpackaging' action. I am also aware that this is a common problem and there are some similar questions here on AskUbuntu however I have tried all of the solutions presented and none are working. As someone with little experience in Linux any help would be great! Here is the last few lines before the error message and then the error message.
Unpacking gnuradio (3.10.1.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnuradio-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../3-gnuradio-dev_3.10.1.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnuradio-dev (3.10.1.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libuhd4.6.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libuhd4.6.0_4.6.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuhd4.6.0:amd64 (4.6.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libuhd-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libuhd-dev_4.6.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuhd-dev (4.6.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-libuhd4.5.0_4.5.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuhd4.5.0:amd64 (4.5.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-msYDXQ/6-libuhd4.5.0_4.5.0.0- 
0ubuntu1~jammy1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/uhd/cal/cal_metadata.fbs', which is also in package 
libuhd4.6.0:amd64 4.6.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1
Selecting previously unselected package uhd-host.
Preparing to unpack .../7-uhd-host_4.6.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking uhd-host (4.6.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-msYDXQ/6-libuhd4.5.0_4.5.0.0-0ubuntu1~jammy1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Use these commands in order in the terminal:
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo cd /var/lib/dpkg/
sudo mv info/ info_bak
sudo mkdir info
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo mv info/* info_bak/
sudo rm -rf info
sudo mv info_bak info
The original source is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70700325/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-when-using-sudo-apt-install
